# React titles- not displaying on Firefox and Safari phone browsers

Tags: css, reactjs

I'm trying to figure out why my react-title won't display at all in Firefox and Safari browsers,

while when I open the application on a Chrome everything is displayed.

What can be a possible solution for this? where should I begin to figure out the reason?

To be more specific the library I'm using for the title is **react-titles**.

Link to package: https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-titles

Help would be much appreciated!

Comment: Are you able to provide some code?

Comment: Well there isn't much code really, its as simple as importing the actual package in the project and the syntax will be:
<Title text1="TEST TITLE" text2="PROJECT" open={true}/>

Comment: I looked into the package a little more and saw that it is not widely used and that it has not been updated in 3 years. I'd recommend looking at the repo (https://github.com/bigfanjs/react-titles), and just using the library that is under the hood yourself (react-motion https://github.com/chenglou/react-motion).